# tvOS 10 - make the only button in a UIScrollView to go out of focus when scrolled past it

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, tvos, swift3

I am working on a tvOS 10 project, with Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0. 
I have a scroll view that has 2 views under it. In one of these views there is a button, the only button in the entire scrollview.

[image]

The scrollview scrolls fine, but when the button comes on focus, it does not go out of focus anymore. I can still scroll past the button. But the button stays still in focus (zoomed out), I can not press it but it is in focus. I can only press it if the the visible view is really on top of the button.

This is pretty much all the code I have in viewDidLoad()

```
// Set the scrolling content
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1920.0, height: 2800.0)

// makes the labels focusable, so it will scroll.`enter code here`
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowe[![enter image description here][1]][1]dTouchTypes = [
UITouchType.indirect.rawValue ]
scrollView.directionalPressGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
```

I want to make it so the button stays in focus as the scroll view is passing the button. But once the scroll view goes past or above the button, I want to be out of focus. So, if the user scrolls back down again it will come on focus.
[image]
[image]